# SQLSRV PDO could not be found

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm trying to configure `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` on Windows 7 x64, with on board XAMPP x86.

I've correctly installed the SQL Native Client 2012 and the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64) package (I don't know if the last one is needed or not).

I've copied to C:\xampp\php\ext\ both the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` and the `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` libraries downloaded from the unofficial release found [here](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/discussions/441706).

Then I've edited the php.ini adding the two libraries and restarted the Apache web server but in the **phpinfo()** page there are not traces of the sqlsrv driver.

The Apache error log says:

```
[21-Jan-2014 10:56:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - Could not find the specified module.

 in Unknown on line 0

[21-Jan-2014 11:01:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - Could not find the specified module.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

What am I doing wrong? If I try to open the specified paths I can correctly find the 2 dll.

Comment: There's no official 64-bit release of the SQLSRV extension. Do you have one from a third-party or you're trying to run the 32-bit version?

Comment: as said, I'm running PHP on 32 bit

Comment: Then you need 32-bit versions of everything, including Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. (Sorry, I misread parts of your question.)

Comment: You also need to ensure that the "VC" version of those DLLs match the one used by Xampp.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed the x86 version of the VC++ and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed this:

- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64)

... but you need the x86 version since that's the architecture of your extension.