# SQLSRV works for CLI only but not from APACHE webserver

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, sqlsrv

I am using sqlsrv to connect to an MS SQL database on my localhost without any problem. Recently, I have installed the 'sqlsrv' driver on a test server  running Windows Server 2012 R2, that uses the same version of PHP as my localhost `(php 5.5.19 - xampp)`.

Running database scripts from CLI of the test server works PERFECTLY fine.
eg: "`D:\MYXAMPP\php\php.exe D:\MYXAMPP\htdocs\test\test.php`" will connect to an mssql db, select some content and print it to screen without error.

However, same scripts complain driver not found when opened from Web interface. I tried checking php error logs, and i found a startup error

```
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\MYXAMPP\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\MYXAMPP\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found."
```

I tried restarting apache but same error keeps showing up. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution this problem. It turns out the server environment Visual C++ Redistributable x86 version. As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256549/sqlsrv-pdo-could-not-be-found), the architecture of sqlsrv extension is x86, thus requires the x86 VC++ even on a x64 machine.

I noticed this when starting apache using a batch script distributed with xampp, instead of using the xampp control panel, a pop up would occur stating **"Missing MSVCP110.dll"**, which I found was linked to VC++ 2012. I downloaded it from [microsoft's website](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU3/vcredist_x86.exe), and restarted apache without any errors. From there on SQLSRV has been working fine for both APACHE and CLI interfaces.

I still don't know why in the first place the CLI php API loaded the extension, while the apache php API couldn't in the same environment. I am researching that.